# Scrapy loop - xpath selector escaping object it is applied to and returning all records?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'll start with the scrapy code I'm trying to use to iterate through a collection of vehicles and extract the model and price:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        split_url = response.url.split("/")
        listings = hxs.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'listing-item')]")
        for vehicle in listings:
            item = Vehicle()
            item['make'] = split_url[5]
            item['price'] = vehicle.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'price')]/text()").extract()
            item['description'] = vehicle.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'title-module')]/h2/a/text()").extract()
            yield item
```

I was expecting that to loop through the listings and return the price only for the single vehicle being parsed, but it is actually adding an array of all prices on the page to each vehicle item.

I assume the problem is in my xpath selectors - is `"//div[contains(@class,'price')]/text()"` somehow allowing the parser to look at divs outside the single vehicle that should be getting parsed each time?

For reference, if I do `listings[1]` it returns only 1 listing, hence the loop should be working.

Edit: I added the line `print vehicle.extract()` above, and confirmed that `vehicle` is definitely only a single item (and it changes each time the loop iterates). How is the xpath selector applied to vehicle able to escape the vehicle object and return all prices?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I have consulted the document that you have referred. Providing the modified code here so that it would be helpful to beginners like me. Note that the usage of `'.'` in the xpath `.//div[contains(@class,'title-module')]/h2/a/text()`

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    split_url = response.url.split("/")
    listings = hxs.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'listing-item')]")
    for vehicle in listings:
        item = Vehicle()
        item['make'] = split_url[5]
        item['price'] = vehicle.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'price')]/text()").extract()
        item['description'] = vehicle.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'title-module')]/h2/a/text()").extract()
        yield item
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve the problem with the aid of the manual, [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html). In summary, the xpath was indeed escaping the iteration because I neglected to put a period in front of the `//` which meant that it was escaping to the root node every time.